# Is Eulerian Path (or Eulerian Cycle) definable in Monadic Second Order Logic?

Tags: graph-theory, lo.logic, finite-model-theory

Does there exist a monadic second order logic formula which is satisfied by a graph if and only if it has an Eulerian path (or Eulerian cycle).

I am looking for properties of graphs which are polynomial time testable but cannot be defined in MSO. I am more inclined to examples of properties from standard textbooks as it is meant for a CS (engineering) crowd and not a CS theory crowd.

Comment: Just think for your self: (1) is it possible to express connectivity in MSOL? (2) Is it possible to express the even degree condition in MSOL?

Answer (score 7):

Parity cannot be expressed in MSOL (see for instance http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~janos/COURSES/236331-15/Lec-1.pdf), but connectedness Yes. Using instead $C_2$MSOL, one can express the existence of an eulerian cycle by using the equivalent characterisation : connected and every vertex has degree even.